# Convert unit measures for a problem from zill book

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, unit-of-measure

I have some questions about a solution for a problem from Zill book "A first course in differential equations 10th edition". I attached an image with the problem [PROBLEM AND SOLUTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aO8Y.jpg).

I have the solution, but I don't understand it, I don't understand the part which implies the conversion of unit measures. I know that I can take $g = 32\cdot\frac{ft}{s^2}$, but then what?
So my questions are:

1. how to compute (convert unit measures) $\frac{4 pound}{32 \cdot \frac{ft}{s^2}}$ to become $\frac{1}{8}$ ? **pound** is a unit measure for weight, **ft** is for distance (like meter),  **s** is for time. So, how they (in image) simplify that raport - division?
2. Then, for the next step: I know that $\omega^2 = \frac{k}{m}$, with $m  =\frac{1}{8}slug~~$ and $k = 16\frac{lb}{ft}$. But what about this division: $$\frac{k}{m} = \frac{16\frac{lb}{ft}}{\frac{1}{8}slug} = 128 \frac{lb \cdot slug}{ft} $$ And again, how can I make this division? **lb** and **slug** are units of measure for weight and **ft** is for distance. How can I reduce them?

Comment: I believe there's a distinction between units of weight, such as _slug_ and units of mass, such as _pounds_. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(unit)

Answer (score 1):

Were the problem and solution written by different people? There's no need to commit to a new mass unit if you know the relations between weight ($F_g$), mass ($m$), gravitational acceleration ($g$), angular frequency ($\omega$), the spring constant ($k$), and the period ($T$):

$$\begin{align}
F_g &= mg \\
\omega^2 &= \frac{k}{m} \\
T &=\frac{2\pi}{\omega} \text{.}
\end{align}$$

That's because you can eliminate $m$ and $\omega$ to get

$$\begin{split}
T &= 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{F_g}{gk}} \\
&\approx 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{
4\,\mathrm{lb_f}}{
(32\,\mathrm{ft}\,\mathrm{s}^{-2})(16 \,\mathrm{lb_f}\,\mathrm{ft}^{-1})}} \\
&\approx \boxed{0.6 \,\mathrm{s}}\text{.}
\end{split}$$

The solution you provided has carelessly lost units.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, **lb** is a measure for *weight*, i.e., a measure for *force*, while **slug** is a measure for mass. The problem is that in common talk we do not make a distinction between them. Given that

$$1 \;\mathit{slug}=1 \;\mathit{lb}\;\frac{s^2}{\mathit{ft}},$$

it's easy to obtain

$$\frac{16\frac{lb}{ft}}{\frac{1}{8}slug}=128\frac{\frac{lb}{ft}}{\mathit{lb}\;\frac{s^2}{\mathit{ft}}}=128\frac{1}{s^2}.$$

As I'm not a physicist myself, I don't know if these are the units to be expected.

Comment: This looks fine, but there is 1/(s^2) which should dissappear somehow..